# ZUK Z1 bricked?

Tags: adb, boot-loop, twrp, unbricking, bootloader

my device had gone into a boot loop condition where It can't

- be detected by adb or computer even in fastboot or recovery mode
- hence, twrp sideload not working
- can't push files into and zuk is having no sd card

and some other resources might be useful,

- has twrp on it
- bootloader is unlocked
- pc with adb :)

please help immediately.. and thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have bricked your device if you would have different device I would have provided better instructions however snapdragon chipsets are hard to flash however give this a try Download cynogen os from here-

https://forum.xda-developers.com/zuk-z1/development/rom-cyanogen-os-12-1-yog4pas3oh-t3248820/page1

And install it through your TWRP.
In case if you had a backup through twrp you can restore it hope it helps

Without a sd card its not possible so arrange it from somewhere or try QFIL flash tool and stock rom as you have a pc.

Follow this guide:
http://www.gsmhelpful.com/2017/06/how-to-flash-lenovo-zuk-z1-z1221-with-qfil-flash-tool.html?m=1